# What is actual difference between iPaaS and CloudHub in Mule

Tags: mule, cloudhub

In Latest Mule version I have noticed they are using the terminology as iPaaS for cloudHub. Does any of you know what are the changes in these two terms?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any change in the premise of what Cloudhub is.  It has always been iPaaS as your using it to publish your application for integration.  IaaS will be the AWS and supporting items under the hood, Cloudhub is the iPaaS that your application runs on.  This is just a nomenclature change to be more precise.